# Kotlin: Check if null and cast it directly

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app, I have a map of `<String, Any?>` and the value of the key could be an Int or String or null.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
map[key]?.let {
    val value = it as Int
    // use value here
}
```

If there a way to have a shortcut like Swift

```
if let value = map[key] as? Int {

}
```

So it's like a single line to check for nullity and cast it on the spot

Comment: what's issue in your code?

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
 (map[key] as? Int)?.let {

 }
```